# CSS: Remove specific style without actually removing it from said CSS file

Tags: html, css

I am trying to mobilize a webpage. I to keep most of the current styles, but I also want to either override, or remove other styles. I know `!important` will override a style, but what if I just want to remove that specific style completely for the current page without removing it from the style sheet?

For example, what if I wanted to remove `width` or `min-width` from an element's style, but I did not want to specify another `width`. I am using jQuery Mobile, which takes care of a lot of those styles.

In this example I would have the files `Styles.css` and `StylesMobile.css`, where `Style.css` would have the following:

```
.buttonStyle {
  width: 100px;
  text-align: left; 
}
```

while `StylesMobile.css` has:

```
.buttonStyle {
  height: 10%;
  color: Red; 
}
```

I still want the `text-align: left;` from `Styles.css`, but not the width (along with the `StylesMobile.css`).

Comment: You might want to take a look at [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries). This way it's easier to work with different types of screens and using certain styles.

Comment: In StylesMobile.css, you just need to overwrite width:100px by width:auto; to remove width properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CSS media queries` is what you are looking for.

In this case, you wrote an example with width. If you want to override width in the mobile stylesheet, just use `width: auto`. Or set width only for resolution higher than any pixels (media queries as I wrote above).

Answer (score 1):

The default value of `width` is `auto`. so you can reset it by specifying `width:auto !important`

Answer (score 0):

You could try use specificity and making the button style for stylemobile more specfic such as .aclass .anotherclass .buttonStyle and that should override the normal buttonStyle